# In CSS 'padding-left-bottom', something like that is present?

Tags: css

I have header navigator tabs like

[image: Img]

with styles as below

```
.navigation {
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-bottom: 0 none;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
    color: #264B9B;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
}
```

If I drop the `padding-bottom: 1px;`, then image

[image: Img]

Padding left bottom side is looking fine, but padding right bottom side is not correct.

How to correct this styling?

EDIT:
The html source in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HENjp/)

Comment: Please, write also the html code. In this way we can see how the boxes are placed

Comment: Please update on jsfiddle.net

Comment: You should read this: http://css-tricks.com/tabs-with-round-out-borders/

Comment: @KDavid and all: sorry for getting back late. I have edited the question with jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="navigation">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.navigation {
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-bottom: 0 none;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
    color: #264B9B;
    width:100px;
    height:80px;
    position:relative;
}
.navigation div{
    border-left: 1px solid red;
    width:100px;
    height:8px;
    bottom:-8px;
    position:absolute;
}
.left{
    border-radius:0;
    right:0px;
}
.right{
    border-radius:0 0 0 8px;
    right:-101px;
}
```

​
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ujC95/